# protractor 2.0 .map not returning element

Tags: dictionary, protractor

I recently migrated from protractor 1.8 to 2.0 (https://github.com/angular/protractor)

I have a problem with understanding how did the way .map works changed. Normally I would find elements and then map them like this:

```
locator.all(by.css('.whatever'))
    .map(function(element){
        return {
            ele: element,
            name: element.getText()
        };
    })
    .then(function(elements){
         if (elements[x].name ==='sth') {
         //do something on elements[x].ele
         }
    });
```

The problem is that in newest version of protractor .element is no longer a promise. So now when I run code like this not only does it not work, but protractor freezes without returning any stacktrace whatsoever.

How should I go around this problem (mapping a list of DOM elements) in newest version of protractor?

Thanks for Your help;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten around this issue with something like the following.

```
locator.all(by.css('.whatever'))
.map(function(element){
    return {
        click: function () {
          element.click();
        },
        name: element.getText()
    };
})
.then(function(elements){
     if (elements[x].name ==='sth') {
        elements[x].click();
     }
});
```